# Tkinter: smaller button

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I am trying to create a grid of small buttons that serve as "status lamps", i.e. they background is changed according to the data they represent (green representing ok values, red = bad).

Currently, I create buttons with:

```
buttonL3_0_1 = tk.Button(frameL3,bg='#003399',relief='flat',width=1,borderwidth=0,height=1)
```

However the default tkinter button size is to large. I am hoping to pack 60x24 or at least 30x48 buttons.  As You might guess, these represent minutes of a day. After the data for a given day is loaded, good minutes will be represented by green buttons.

Is there any way to further reduce button size? Or perhaps other method to implement this. I also provide a small screenshot of an 1x12 button array. I had to take a picture with my phone because of this stupid mint cynamon / AMD Catalyst / Multi monitor setup bug that makes all my screenshots black.

I am hoping to pack atleast 30 buttons in the same width. Of course, height reduction would also be appreciated. At this stage, the background of all buttons is blue. [image]

Comment: First off, why not use labels with backgrounds?

Comment: Because they need to be pushable, i.e. process a command when clicked upon.

Thank You for Your participation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I just managed to find a solution: I used an 6x6 transparent gif as the buttons image and this solved the problem. The status functionality remains since the gif is transparent.